# Procedure or function *** has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Whenever I try to insert something into my database, I get this error:

> Procedure or function sp_Customer_Insert has too many arguments specified.

Tried to search for help online but couldn't find anything helpful.

EDIT: I deleted `p_cust_id` from insert parameters, but it still gives the same error, help please I really don't see what I'm doing wrong

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Customer_Insert]
 @p_cust_name nvarchar(50)
,@p_cust_address nvarchar(50)
,@p_cust_city nvarchar(50)
,@p_cust_state nvarchar(5)
,@p_cust_zip nvarchar(10)
,@p_cust_country nvarchar(50)
,@p_cust_contact nvarchar(50)
,@p_cust_email  nvarchar(255)
,@p_cust_birthday datetime
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO customers
       (cust_name
       ,cust_address
       ,cust_city
       ,cust_state
       ,cust_zip
       ,cust_country
       ,cust_contact
       ,cust_email
       ,cust_birthday)
 VALUES
       (@p_cust_name
       ,@p_cust_address
       ,@p_cust_city 
       ,@p_cust_state
       ,@p_cust_zip
       ,@p_cust_country
       ,@p_cust_contact
       ,@p_cust_email
       ,@p_cust_birthday
       );
END;
```

ASP code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="223px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="cust_id">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_id" HeaderText="cust_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="cust_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_name" HeaderText="cust_name" SortExpression="cust_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_address" HeaderText="cust_address" SortExpression="cust_address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_city" HeaderText="cust_city" SortExpression="cust_city" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_state" HeaderText="cust_state" SortExpression="cust_state" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_zip" HeaderText="cust_zip" SortExpression="cust_zip" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_country" HeaderText="cust_country" SortExpression="cust_country" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_contact" HeaderText="cust_contact" SortExpression="cust_contact" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_email" HeaderText="cust_email" SortExpression="cust_email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cust_birthday" HeaderText="cust_birthday" SortExpression="cust_birthday" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CrashCourseConnectionString %>" InsertCommand="sp_Customer_Insert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="sp_CustomerByID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_city" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_state" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_zip" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_contact" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_birthday" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCustomers" Name="cust_id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#

```
public static DataTable InsertCustomer(string Name, string Address, string City, string State, string Zip, string Country, string Contact, string Email, DateTime BDay)
{
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_Customer_Insert", CData.CData.GetConnection());

        DA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_name", Name);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_address", Address);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_city", City);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_state", State);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_zip", Zip);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_country", Country);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_contact", Contact);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_email", Email);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cust_birthday", BDay);

        return DT;
```

Can someone help?

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can't use `//` to comment in aspx code. Use `<!-- <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_id" Type="Int32" /> -->` instead, or just delete the line since it's not needed anyway.

Comment: I deleted it completely. Still the same error

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Not clear what the `InsertCustomer` method is doing. For insert SP, you are adding `SelectCommand.Parameter`s instead of `InsertCommand.Parameter`s, and not inserting at last. Creating null `DataTable` and returning it. Are you really using this?

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no `@p_cust_id` parameter in `sp_Customer_Insert`, you need to remove `<asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_id" Type="Int32" />` from `<InsertParameters>`:

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_address" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_city" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_state" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_zip" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_country" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_contact" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_birthday" Type="DateTime" />
</InsertParameters>
```

Answer (score 2):

We get this error when we try to insert more parameters than we have defined

As in your .aspx page code in  you have defined one extra parameter i.e

```
<asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_id" Type="Int32" />
```

Remove this line as you are not inserting id field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete `<asp:Parameter Name="p_cust_id" Type="Int32" />` from `<InsertParameters>` in your ASP file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which turned out to be due to the use of a `DataKeyName` which was not used as a parameter to my (Update) Stored Procedure.  It seemed to be included with the update parameters collection although I could not find any documentation to explain why.  I corrected the problem at the time by adding the DataKey as an (unused) parameter in the Stored Procedure.  I did not need to add to the `updateParameters` collection.

This was just a temporary fix to test if this would resolve the issue - in the end I recoded the page so I did not use a DataKey.

In this instance I would try adding a declaration of `cust_id` to `sp_Customer_Insert`.